# How to finish a View Class used as a splash screen in android?

Tags: android, view, back, splash-screen

I have used a `View` Class as a Splash screen with some custom `animations`.
The splash class is working fine, it goes to next `activity` successfully but when i click back button, the splash screen is returning. There is no `onPause` method for `View` class? Anybody please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to add the `noHistory` attribute to the manifest file.

Add:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

To the attributes of the splash screen activity to prevent it being returned to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call finish() on your activity when you are done with it. It should put it out of the activity stack.